# Sull'uso di "glie lo" invece di "glielo"

Tags: word-usage, orthography, pronouns

Nel romanzo *Se una notte d'inverno un viaggiatore* di Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Sarà la regola della clandestinità che *glie lo* impone?

Le parole "glie lo" in questa frase hanno attirato la mia attenzione perché nei miei libri di grammatica ho imparato che questa combinazione di pronomi si scrive "glielo". Ho trovato nel [dizionario Hoepli "Si dice o non si dice?"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/G/glielo-glie-lo.shtml) che alcuni scrittori usano "glie lo" invece di "glielo".

La mia domanda è sull'uso che si fa di questa forma, "glie lo", e anche "glie la", "glie li", "glie le", "glie ne": si tratta di forme poco usate? Ci sono veramente alcuni scrittori attuali che preferiscono queste forme?

Comment: Non leggo troppo quindi non saprei (anche se a naso non credo, nella mia ignoranza sinceramente se lo avessi trovato su un libro l'avrei preso per un refuso), comunque qui ci sono altre informazioni: http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_503.html

Comment: Curiosamente adesso sto leggendo *Ti con zero*, anche questo di Italo Calvino, e nel racconto *L'origine degli Uccelli* ho trovato questa frase: «Il vecchio U(h) gliele strappa di sotto, l'uovo casca, l'uccello vola via». Mi piacerebbe sapere se, come sembra suggerire Hoepli, alcuni autori usano sistematicamente le forme staccate.

Comment: Come suggerisce l'Accademia della Crusca, l'uso in due parole è "letterario", quindi si può supporre che sia diffuso soprattutto tra gli scrittori. Ngram può essere uno strumento per verificarne l'uso. La mia sensazione è che anche a livello letterario sia sempre meno usato.

Comment: Nel [blog Lo SciacquaLingua di Fausto Raso](http://faustoraso.blogspot.com.es/2013_01_01_archive.html?m=1) si può leggere: "Personalmente preferiamo la grafia non univerbata, anche se considerata di uso prettamente letterario o raro, perché, come fa notare il linguista Amerindo Camilli, «la grafia da consigliare è glie lo, glie ne (ecc., nota del redattore) che si conforma a me lo, te ne, ecc. Glielo, gliene sono due eccezioni ingiustificate»."

Comment: Un altro esempio tratto di *Gli amori difficili*, un libro di Italo Calvino che ho anche letto. Si tratta dell'inizio del racconto *L'avventura di un viaggiatore*: «Federico V., abitante in una cittadina dell'Italia settentrionale, amava Cinzia U., residente a Roma. Ogni volta che le sue occupazioni *glie lo* permettevano, prendeva il treno per la capitale.»

Comment: Nello stesso libro, nel racconto *L'avventura di un bandito* si può leggere: «Certo, se non l’arrestavano oggi l’arrestavano domani, ma la flagranza non c’era, se tutto andava bene lo mandavano fuori subito. Aspettare lì ancora due, tre ore senza sigarette, in quello sgabuzzino... chi *glie lo* faceva fare?»

Comment: Si possono trovare vari esempi dell'uso disgiunto del termine glielo,         che rimane  comunque ben più raro della forma congiunta ed è sicuramente molto meno usato dagli autori contemporanei. Lo stesso blog che citi la definisce una forma "letteraria e rara". A questo punto mi sembra chiaro che se qualcuno preferisce usarla, può farlo in quanto non è sbagliata. La Crusca e Treccani non la consigliano.

Comment: Non è “ingiustificato”. Il pronome *glie* non è mai da solo, ma *deve* avere un altro pronome che lo accompagni; la grafia unita riflette questa particolarità grammaticale.

Answer (score 2):

L'evidenza che ci offre [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glie%20lo%2C%20glielo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cglie%20lo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglielo%3B%2Cc0)  è di un uso poco comune  della forma staccata  *glie lo.*

Secondo [L'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/glielo-potremmo-spiegare-cos):

> - Alla terza persona, invece, i due pronomi atoni si fondono normalmente in un'unica parola: glielo, gliela, glieli, gliele. ***La grafia corretta e diffusa è oggi dunque quella unita***; quella staccata è certamente possibile, ma di uso letterario e antico, oggi assai raro.

Secondo [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_503.html):

> - ***Consigliamo l’uso della moderna e contemporanea forma univerbata glielo, nonostante l’italiano antico – fin dentro il Novecento di uno scrittore atipico come Federigo Tozzi, per esempio - conosca bene la forma analitica glie lo.***
> - Esiste una dissimmetria, rispetto alle forme composte con le particelle pronominali di prima, seconda, quarta e quinta persona (me lo, te lo, ce lo, ve lo), che forse un giorno si colmerà con l’uso, attraverso un riallineamento. Per ora, atteniamoci alla grafia vigente.

Il commento che segue cerca di spiegare perché viene usata la versione in due termini:

***[Glielo o glie lo](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/G/glielo-glie-lo.shtml)?***

> - Dicono le grammatiche che il pronome personale gli seguíto dai pronomi lo, la, li, le, ne, si fonde con questi in un’unica parola, variando la forma in glie: e abbiamo così glielo, gliela, glieli, gliele, gliene.
> - Però le stesse grammatiche insegnano anche che i pronomi mi, ti, si, ci, vi, seguíti dagli stessi pronomi lo, la ecc., trasformandosi in me, te, se, ce, ve, formano i pronomi composti me lo, te ne, se li, ce la, ve le eccetera, sempre scritti coi due termini ben distinti. ***È evidente che questa differenza di trattamento non può avere nessuna giustificazione né logica né grafica.***
> - L’uso e anche molti scrittori stanno facendo giustizia di questa stranezza, per cui possiamo sentirci liberi di adottare, se vogliamo, una grafia più coerente, separando anche glielo e famiglia: glie lo, glie la, glie li, glie le, glie ne.
> - S’intende che quando questi pronomi composti hanno funzione di suffisso di una forma verbale non si potranno scrivere che in una parola sola: dirglielo, fargliene eccetera, come del resto accade anche per dirtelo, farmelo e simili.

(Hoepli)

Comment: La spiegazione di Hoepli è esattamente quello che ho letto io (vedi il link della mia domanda). Mi piacerebbe avere più informazioni sull'argomento.

Comment: @Charo - ho aggiunto le spiegazioni della Crusca e di Treccani, che mi sembrano tutte convergere sul fatto che l'uso contemporaneo è quello dell'unica parola. La forma in  due parole non è  scorretta, ma obsoleta e poco usata. Ngram conferma l'uso della forma in un'unica parola è quella molto più diffusa. Cosa posso fare di più?

Comment: Personalmente, per quel che conta, non userei mai la forma in due parole.

Comment: @Josh61personalmente, sempre per quel che conta, se esistesse un movimento per l'utilizzo della forma in due parole, vi aderirei (ma purtroppo non esiste)

Comment: Potresti fondarlo tu :)

Comment: Nei paesi di lingua tedesca certi linguisti hanno fondato gruppi di lavoro per la riforma dell'ortografia tedesca, che, dopo un lavoro di parecchi anni e tre congressi a Vienna hanno convinto i governi di Germania, Austria e Lussemburgo a dare validità legale alla nuova ortografia, soprattutto per quanto riguarda la scuola. Obiettivo della riforma è stata soprattutto la semplificazione attraverso la razionalizzazione, senza sconvolgimenti. Uno dei risultati è stato proprio lo "scollamento" di parole che nel tempo si erano "incollate" (p.es. _radfahren_ → _Rad fahren_, andare in bicicletta).

Comment: @WalterTross - molto interessante, in Italia invece la Crusca rischia di chiudere per mancanza di fondi!!